# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occured in WTApp

Tags: c#, winforms

I am converting an App from VB.NET to C# in WinForms apps.

The problem arose when I realised that you can't access other forms directly like you can in VB.NET e.g :

```
Public Class frmMain
     Private Sub Preferences_Click(sender...
           frmPreferences.Show()                                           
     End Sub
End Class
```

So I had a look online and It seemed like I had to declare a reference to the form before I could change its controls' values. So:

I now have two separate forms. One named `frmPreferences` which looks like this without the extra bits of code:

```
public partial class frmPreferences : Form
    {
        frmMain frmMain = new frmMain();
    }
```

And the other, `frmMain`, just declaring the other form:

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        frmPreferences frmPreferences = new frmPreferences();
    }
```

The Call stack shows:

> WTAppCSharp.exe!WTAppCSharp.frmMain.frmMain() Line 17   C#
>       WTAppCSharp.exe!WTAppCSharp.frmPreferences.frmPreferences() Line 38 C#
>   WTAppCSharp.exe!WTAppCSharp.frmMain.frmMain() Line 17   C#
>       WTAppCSharp.exe!WTAppCSharp.frmPreferences.frmPreferences() Line 38 C#
> ....

I'm just not sure how to reference the forms correctly, or, what I'm doing wrong :(

Hope someone can help :)

Comment: remove `frmMain frmMain = new frmMain();` from `frmPreferences` constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've created an infinite loop.  Your two constructors reference each other. You can remove the reference from frmPreferences or even get rid of the parameterless constructor altogether.

```
    public frmMain()
    {  //this is all you need.
        frmPreferences frmPreferences = new frmPreferences();
        frmPreferences.Show();
    }
```

That will fix it, and pop the Preferences form for you.  I would change all of your variable names to NOT be the same name and case as the class they call.  It will make sense when troubleshooting, and you may start getting errors from intellisense saying you can't do that anyway.

Edit: To be more specific, by using default values on your properties, you are calling the parameterless constructor for the other object to fill in that property.  Which then calls your first object's property, which then calls the second again, and so on .

Comment: Yes, but I need to access both forms from each other so removing:
`frmMain frmMain = new frmMain();` from `frmPreferences`
would give me errors like:
'An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property"Control.Show"'.

The VB code at the top is just an example. I have code referencing in each opposite form.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks!

Comment: In case you haven't found it yet, the properties of a `Form` you need to access them from each other involve the `Parent` property (which in this case is your frmMain instance), public child form properties, and the `Owner` property.  Documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent(v=vs.110).aspx